# why only softmax and random initialization for weights initialization are supported in keras.applications

Tags: tensorflow, keras, softmax, sigmoid, imagenet

I'm using keras.applications.Xception for multi-label classification tasks.
I'm trying to do so by setting classifier_activation='sigmoid' and setting using binary focal loss for loss function.
For the initial training, I set weights=None for random uniform weight initialization, but I want to save and resume the training in between the sessions.

Here's the question, when trying to resume training with weights='best_weights.hdf5', I get an error(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/imagenet_utils.py#L430)
`Only None and softmax activations are allowed for the classifier_activation argument when using pretrained weights, with include_top=True`. So, I just added `activations.get('softmax')` in line 427 and the problem seems to be solved.

1. Will there be any consequences by ignoring the error message?
2. Am I getting the error because they are not meant to be used for multi-label classification tasks? or are they still usable for the tasks too? (I trained Xception for nearly 40 epochs and looks good so far.)

Comment: You are reading too much from the error message, if you set weights, it should be a string like "imagenet", not the path of your own weights. You can just instance the model and call load_weights to load weights from a file.

Comment: Totally makes sense, I was confused by `weights: one of None (random initialization), 'imagenet' (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded.`. "Path to the weights file" was also for ImageNet trained, I guess. I didn't know the existence of load_weights and it sure is right to use the method rather than editing the library code. Thanks!